# Get specific child data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to access a child from a node. I have only "value" for a specific child and to get the `Type` value from the same node.

I have to return the value:

[image: Structure]

I've done a lot of googling and I just can't figure out how this works. My current version of the java code is this.

```
private String GetCategory(String sName ) {
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category");
    Query query = db.orderByValue().equalTo("Salary");//.orderByValue().equalTo("Salary");


    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String eType = userSnapshot.child("Type").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("Catagory","Value"+ eType);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: need to get the type and icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Get a specific node inside `Category`

If you want to get the node which `id` is 1, you could try this:

```java
private String GetCategory(String sName ) {
    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category");

    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                // check for desired id here
                if(userSnapshot.getKey().equals("1")) {
                    String icon = userSnapshot.child("Icon").getValue().toString();
                    String name = userSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                    String type = userSnapshot.child("Type").getValue().toString();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

Output of the code above:

```
icon = "01"
name = "Salary"
type = "Icome"
```

##### Get all nodes inside `Category`

If you want to read all the node inside `Category`, just provide an `array` of `hash map` or `class` and change the `onDataChange` method like this:

```java
ArrayList<ExampleClass> array = new ArrayList<>();
for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    ExampleClass example = new ExampleClass();
    example.setIcon(userSnapshot.child("Icon").getValue().toString());
    example.setName(userSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString());
    example.setType(userSnapshot.child("Type").getValue().toString());
}
```

but first, you have to create the `ExampleClass` file with `setter` and `getter` functions inside it.

Output:

```
array[0].getIcon = "01"
array[0].getName = "Salary"
array[0].getType = "Icome"

...

array[2].getIcon = "07"
array[2].getName = "Other Income"
array[2].getType = "Income"
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a reference to the `Category` node, attaching a listener to getting all children of the node and do a comparison on the client, is not the best option to go ahead with. If your node will contain **1 MIL** children, are you willing to download all of them in order to read **only** a single one? That's an incredible waste of bandwidth and resources. What you should do, is to create a Query that can return only the information you are interested in. Assuming you need the information from the first child, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference categoryRef = rootRef.child("Category");
Query queryByName = categoryRef.orderByChild("Name").equalTo("Salary");
queryByName.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String type = snapshot.child("Type").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", type);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
 Income
```

Assuming that the first object is the only one that satisfies the Query, then you'll get **only** a single element from the database. This is extremely **fast** and consumes an incredibly small amount of data.

Comment: Hey AV114! Have you tried the solution in my answer? Does it work faster?